# C++ How Would I print A Graph?

Tags: c++, tuples

So I put together a graph class containing tuples, each containing two integers taken from source.txt, and also a printGraph function, but I try to use it in my driver and doesn't output anything. I have my text file in the right place, and I'm sure I inserted the integers and tuples the right way, but I'm not sure. I think it has to do with I set up my print function and how I'm implementing it. I would very much appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong and maybe a possible solution. Thank you

```
void printGraph(Graph t) {

map<int, Vertex*> vertices = t.getVertices();

for (map<int, Vertex*>::iterator it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it) {
    cout << it->first << ": ";
    vector<Edge *> edges = it->second->getEdges();
    for (vector<Edge *>::iterator jit = edges.begin(); jit != edges.end(); ++jit) {
        int l1 = (*jit)->getV1()->getLabel();
        int l2 = (*jit)->getV2()->getLabel();
        if (l1 != it->first) { cout << l1 << ", "; }
        if (l2 != it->first) { cout << l2 << ", "; }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}


const int numberStreets = 10 ;
int main() 
{
std::ifstream infile("source.txt");
tuple<int, int> streets[numberStreets];
int a, b;


if (!infile) {
    cout << "File not found" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}

int i = 0;
while (infile >> a >> b)
{   
    streets[i] = make_tuple(a, b);
    i++;
}

Graph city(numberStreets);
for (int i = 0; i < numberStreets; i++) 
{
    city.addEdge(get<0>(streets[i]), get<1>(streets[i]));
}
printGraph(city);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Here's my Graph Class

```
class Graph {
vector<Edge*> edges;
map<int, Vertex*> vertices;
public: 
Graph(const int){}
Vertex *  addVertex(int label) {
    Vertex * v = new Vertex(label);
    vertices[label] = v;
    return v;
}
map<int, Vertex*> getVertices() { return vertices; }
vector<Edge*> getEdges() { return edges; }

Edge * addEdge(int from, int to) {

    if (vertices.find(from) != vertices.end() && vertices.find(to) != vertices.end()) {
        Vertex * vfrom = vertices.find(from)->second;
        Vertex * vto = vertices.find(to)->second;
        Edge * e = new Edge(vfrom, vto);
        (*vfrom).addEdge(e);
        edges.push_back(e);
        return e;
    }
    else {

        return 0;
    }
}

Edge * getEdge(int from, int to) {
    if (vertices.find(from) != vertices.end() && vertices.find(to) != vertices.end()) {
        Vertex * v1 = vertices.find(from)->second;
        Vertex* v2 = vertices.find(to)->second;
        Edge * e = (*v1).getEdgeTo(to);
        return e;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}


void removeEdge(int from, int to) {
    Edge * e = getEdge(from, to);
    if (e != 0) {
        edges.erase(remove(edges.begin(), edges.end(), e), edges.end());
        (*e).getV1()->removeEdge(e);
    }
}

Vertex * getVertexWithLabel(int l) {
    if (vertices.find(l) != vertices.end())
        return vertices.find(l)->second;
    else
        return 0;
}

void removeVertex(int l) {
    Vertex * v = getVertexWithLabel(l);
    if (v != 0) {
        vector<Edge *> edges = getVertexWithLabel(l)->getEdges();

        for (vector<Edge *>::iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); ++it) {
            int from = (*it)->getV1()->getLabel();
            int to = (*it)->getV2()->getLabel();
            removeEdge(from, to);
        }
        vertices.erase(l);
    }
    else {

    }
}
};
```

If there's anymore information you need, please ask and I'll edit my question. Thank you.

[image: Here's what my newest debug was like]

Comment: Well, it would be useful to see the `Graph` class for starters... That said: the issue **could be** that you are passing the object `Graph t` by value, instead of by pointer/reference, and thus making a copy of it. If the copy constructor is not implemented correctly, the copy might be different than the original (e.g., contain nothing...). So as a first step, I'd recommend to debug `printGraph`, and see what it gets. (And, also in main, check what the value of `city` is, where `printGraph` is called.)

Comment: I just added the graph class. So I should declare city as a pointer? Then would I still need the const in argument I set up in the constructor? Would I even still need numberStreets?

Comment: Try this: change `void printGraph(Graph t)` to `void printGraph(Graph & t)`. And *don't change* the way it is called: `printGraph(city);`. RE: "city as pointer" --> no need to. RE: const argument in constructor --> In general this has nothing to do with `city` being pointer or not, but as I see, it also does **nothing at all** in the code above, so you could also remove that.

Comment: I changed printGraph, and removed the const int in the constructor, but it's still not showing anything.

Comment: With this kind of code, debugging (probably with a debugger) is really the only way forward. We can't do that for you. Read help section here, and see what is MCVE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I notice is, that only `addEdge` is called, but never `addVertex`. Thus, whenever you call `addEdge`, both `vertices.find(from)` and `vertices.find(to)` will return `vertices.end()` (because the vertices are not there).

I suggest the following steps:

1. Debug the calls to `addEdge`, to see what is going on. (Or, at least check the return value, which would be good practice anyway.) You'll notice the issue I've described.
2. Put in the calls to `addVertex`, and again, debug both calls to `addVertex` and `addEdge`, to ensure that this time the graph is really built. (Even do the debugging if `printGraph` now works, to make sure that it happens how you think it does.)

N.B.: As I said, this is only the first issue I noticed, so I don't guarantee, that after adding `addVertex` calls, it will work.